# File.md5Checksum equivalent for Google Doc files

Tags: google-drive-api

For non-Google Doc files in a Google Drive, I can detect a change by comparing the File.md5Checksum with a previous value.

md5Checksum is null for Google Doc files:

```
 application/vnd.google-apps.*
```

Is there any method besides File.modifiedDate?

Admittedly, it's sort of a corner case: if a doc goes from state A => B => A, then the modifiedDate will change but not the content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File.modifiedDate is definitely a good solution but you should consider using the Changes feed to detect changes to file:

https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-changes

Once you retrieve the Changes feed, you can filter the entries using the `fileId` field.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It looks like there's no way (q=...) to limit the returned change set for the file in question, so I'd have to filter out a potentially large number of changes, looking to see if the one I'm interested changed. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, you can only filter the Changes feed by change id using the pageToken query parameter